# Phalcon model FindFirst on NULL values

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to use `findFirst()` to load models by NULL value of `field`:

```php
$model = MyModel::findFirst([
    'conditions' => 'field=?0',
    'bind' => [
        0 => null,
    ],
    'bindTypes' => [
        0 => Phalcon\Db\Column::BIND_PARAM_NULL,
    ]
]);
```

This does not find the row whose `field` value is **NULL**.

**Question**:

How do I use `findFirst` to load models by NULL value of a field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would personally do

```
$model = MyModel::findFirst(['field is null']);
```